# Android webapp, loading another HTML

Tags: javascript, android, html

I'm creating an Android webapp for a simple login\register using WebView.
My HTML page have a register button (on login.html) that should take the user from the login page to the register page.

My issue is that no matter what method I use to go from pages, nothing work.

My login.HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <script src="jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
<form action="index.html" method="post">
    <div class="imgcontainer">
    </div>
    <h1>Login</h1>
    <div class="container">
        <label><b>Username</b></label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Username" name="uname" required>

        <label><b>Password</b></label>
        <input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="psw" required>

        <button type="submit">Login</button>
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="remember"> Remember me
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <span><p>New User?</p>
        <button type="button" id="regbtn">Register</button>
        </span>
    </div>
</form>
<script>
         $("#regbtn").on("click",function(){
             app.goToRegister();
         });

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

The way I've create the `goToRegister()`:

```
    @JavascriptInterface
    public void goToRegister() {
        context.goToRegister();
    }
```

```
    public void goToRegister(){
        String reg = "register.html";
        //webView.loadUrl("javascript:myFunction(\""+reg+"\")");
        webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/register.html");
    }
```

I had implemented the same method on my `function.js` and as a function within `login.HTML`, neither worked.
Ofcourse when I tried to use the method from `function.js` the button of the HTML was different.

Both page are on the same local project.
When I click the button, nothing happens.

**EDIT:**

I have all the required javascript options enabled:

```
        WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);


        webViewJavaScriptInterface = new WebViewJavaScriptInterface(this);
        webView.addJavascriptInterface(webViewJavaScriptInterface,"app");
        webView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE,null);
        WebView.setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have this error:

```
 @JavascriptInterface
    public void goToRegister() {
        context.goToRegister();
    }
```

here "context" dose not have "goToRegister()" method declared.

```
public class WebAppInterface {
    MainActivity mActivity;


    WebAppInterface(MainActivity a) {
        mActivity = a;
    }


  @JavascriptInterface
    public void goToRegister() {
        mActivity.goToRegister();
    }
}
```

Hope it works... Best of luck.